# Cálculo de frete Correios + PHP

Tags: php, web-service

Como é calculado os valores dos fretes no caso do usuário selecionar mais de um produto em uma loja virtual? Na hora de cadastrar um produto, estamos dando a opção do cliente colocar o comprimento, altura, largura, diâmetro e o peso por produto. No PHP pego dessa forma antes de calcular o frete:

```
$parametros['nVlComprimento'] = '35';
$parametros['nVlAltura'] = '21';
$parametros['nVlLargura'] = '13';
$parametros['nVlDiametro'] = '0';
```

Minha única dúvida é como isso é calculado? No momento estou calculando a quantidade de produtos * o valor do frete que é gerado pela API que estou usando, mas eu não teria que calcular também os valores acima no caso do cliente escolher mais um produto?

Comment: Já trabalhei com Loja Virtual, eu usava a API dos Correios para calcular, enviava os dados como peso etc e o correio retornava o valor. Pq depende do tamanho, peso do produto, local, etc. Por exemplo: https://github.com/newerton/api-correios/blob/master/Correios.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu calculo de maneira separada o frete para cada produto. Como se fosse ter uma embalagem para cada. Depois, somo todos os resultados.

Como o frete dos correios é baseado por volume e peso, não tem como ter certeza do valor exato em caso de mais de um produto, já que não temos como saber o tamanho da caixa final onde vai ser colocado tudo (caso coloque tudo em uma caixa apenas).

Comment: Obrigado a todos.